# Matlab-libsvm - reproducing the decision values from the primal weight vector, linear kernel

Tags: matlab, svm, linear-algebra, libsvm

I'm trying to compare the decision values provided by libsvm's svmpredict with those generated by projection of the data on the primal weight vector w (I'm considering the linear case). For debugging purposes I'm using the same data for training and testing.

w is computed according to the libsvm FAQ. Then I'm calculating the decision values by z=X*w+b.

When the data is separable (n=300, p=1000), the decision values produced by both methods are differently scaled, correlated but not identical (the predicted labels are also not exactly the same):
[image]

When the data is inseparable (n=300, p=10), there's a very weak relation between the values:
[image]

I suspect I've missed something fundamental. Any ideas? Matlab's fitcsvm object does not produce this discrepancy.

Code:

```
%% generate some random data
n=300;
p=1000;
labels=mod(randperm(n)',2)*2-1;
X=randn(n,p);

%% train model
model= svmtrain(labels, X,'-q b 0');

%% produce primal w (libsvm faq)
w = model.SVs' * model.sv_coef;
b = -model.rho;

if model.Label(1) == -1
  w = -w;
  b = -b;
end

primal_decision_values=(X*w+b); %??

%% svmpredict decision values
[predicted_label, accuracy, libsvm_decision_values]=svmpredict(labels,X,model,'-q b 0');

%% comparison
fprintf('label agreement: %g\n',mean(sign(predicted_label)==sign(primal_decision_values)))
scatter(primal_decision_values,libsvm_decision_values); xlabel('primal decision values'); ylabel('libsvm decision values');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default kernel in LibSVM is the RBF Kernel, as described in the documentation:

> `-t` kernel_type : set type of kernel function **(default 2)**
>     0 -- linear: u'*v 
>     1 -- polynomial: (gamma*u'*v + coef0)^degree
>     **2 -- radial basis function**: exp(-gamma*|u-v|^2)
>     3 -- sigmoid: tanh(gamma*u'*v + coef0)
>     4 -- precomputed kernel (kernel values in training_set_file)

With the training command `model= svmtrain(labels, X,'-q b 0');`, you'll thus train a **RBF** support vector machine. A prediction using the primal `w` with the equation `X*w+b` however is only possible for the **linear** SVM.

When training a SVM with a linear kernel:

```
model = svmtrain(labels, X,'-t 0 -q -b 0');
```

you will get a beautiful identity function when comparing the LibSVM function and the prediction with `X*w+b` (with all code except the `svmtrain` identical to your MWE):

[image: comparison]

(It also took me quite a while to figure out that the default is a RBF (2), and not a linear (0) kernel. Who sets such counterintuitive default values?!?)